# Is it possible to integrate an external permission server?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have implemented RBAC with Ory Keto to manage user's permissions based on token's claims. I use Ory Oathkeeper as a reverse proxy which authenticates an user using Ory Hydra and authorizes it using Ory Keto. Now, I want to integrate those services with Firebase/Firestore.

I think it will be possible to integrate Ory Hydra (authentication server) with Firebase/Firestore because it is possible to integrate Auth0 (https://auth0.com/blog/developing-real-time-apps-with-firebase-and-firestore/). That is, I think it's possible to use Hydra's access token(OAuth2) or OpenId token(JWT) to create a custom firebase token and use the latter to authorize access (creating firebase rules).

I was wondering if is possible to use Ory Keto's roles in firebase authorization process. In other words, if is possible to integrate an external permission server in firebase to grant access.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to call out to your third-party authorization server from within Firestore's security rules, as the performance of that would be unpredictable.

What you instead can do is make the information from the third-party authorization server available inside your Firestore security rules. There are two common approaches for this:

1. Make the information available as custom claims in the user's authentication profile.
2. Make the information available inside Firestore itself.

Either of these tasks must be performed from trusted code, so must be run in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

You'd typically put the information in a custom claim if it is small and unlikely to change frequently (as custom claim may take some time to propagate). For example: whether the user is an administrator is typically a one-time change, and fits well within a custom claim. You can then access the custom claims within your security rules with something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;  
    } 
  }
}
```

If authorization information is either bigger or more volatile, it's more common to store that information in the database itself. You can then access it within your security rules with something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/AuthorizedUsers/$(request.auth.id))
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look, but seems to be what I need xD